# Sql Query With Multiple Select's Sorting Error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a sql query which when executed gives an error

"*The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.*"

**the query is**

```
SELECT Count(*)                                AS present, 
       (SELECT Count(counted) 
        FROM   (SELECT attdate AS counted 
                FROM   gtab85 
                WHERE  attdate >= '01/10/2014' 
                       AND attdate <= '11/10/2014' 
                GROUP  BY attdate) AS derived) AS working, 
       gtab86.staffname 
FROM   gtab85 AS A 
       INNER JOIN gtab86 
               ON gtab86.staffid = A.userid 
WHERE  attdate >= '01/10/2014' 
       AND attdate <= '11/10/2014' 
GROUP  BY userid, 
          staffname
```

when i execute the following part

```
SELECT Count(*)                                AS present, 
       (SELECT Count(counted) 
        FROM   (SELECT attdate AS counted 
                FROM   gtab85 
                WHERE  attdate >= '01/10/2014' 
                       AND attdate <= '11/10/2014' 
                GROUP  BY attdate) AS derived) AS working
```

i get results in a unsorted manner.please help me with this fix.

Comment: Obviously the `staffname` is a text or ntext column. If you want it to be used in group by clause, you can convert it into varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert text to varchar:

```
select count(*) as present,
       (select count(counted)  
        from (select attdate as counted 
              from  gtab85 
              where attdate >='01/10/2014' and attdate <='11/10/2014' group by attdate
             ) as derived
       ) as working, 
       convert(varchar(255),gtab86.staffname )
from gtab85 as A 
inner join gtab86 
on gtab86.staffid=A.userid 
where attdate >='01/10/2014' and attdate <='11/10/2014'  
group by userid,convert(varchar(255),gtab86.staffname )
```